# how to filter an xml file using the expressions < or &lt; in xslt?

Tags: xslt

Hi I'm trying to display a number of things that match a certain criteria. In my xml file i have a bunch of 'suppliers'

```
<Suppliers>
 <ASupplier>
  <SupplierId> 12 </SupplierId>
  <SupplierName> Amazon </SupplierName>
  <Email> Something@live.com </Email>
  <StartDate> 01</11</2010 </StartDate>
  <ContractLength> 6 </ContractLength>
  <AnnualTurnover> 1233.32 </AnnualTurnover>
 </ASupplier>
</Suppliers>
```

This is the code from my xslt file

```
<xsl:if test="$SearchType = 'Length'">
 <xsl:for-each select="ASupplier[$SupplierFilter >= ContractLength]">
  <tr>
   <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="../SupplierName"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

the 'SearchType' is a parameter.
The problem im having is that im getting back empty data instead of a table with the name inside. It returns the correct number but without any data i.e. i have 3 suppliers with contract length of 6 or less and if i type 6 and search it brings back 3 table cells but without any data. Any thoughts. 
p.s I have the functions start-with and contains that use similar code and work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input you show lost its XML tags so it is hard to see what the xslt is acting on (I'll put them back).

that said I would guess that

```
<xsl:value-of select="../SupplierName"/>
```

should be

```
<xsl:value-of select="SupplierName"/>
```

If `SupplierName` is a child of `ASupplier`

Comment: My assumption was that the  <> tags got removed, and what you are looking at is the XML without them. You can see it is somewhat structured as such given the "/ASupplier" and "/Suppliers" near the end. I think this is what they were looking for though.

Comment: If you look closely, you can see that the example has opening and closing tags, but they have somehow lost their angle brackets. Based on that, I think it's a good chance you're right that the asker just needs to remove the `../`.

Comment: yes I can see that it's xml without the tag markup but why did the OP remove the tagging, it doesn't make understanding the question any easier.

Comment: Maybe OP was grappling with SO's habit of hiding anything in angle brackets that isn't thoroughly indented and just removed the brackets, but then overcame that battle when it came time to post the XSLT.

Comment: @JLRishe Perhaps, do you think I was too hard on him, OK I suppose so, I'll soften the wording a bit:-)